# Calling powershell script file using parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, powershell, parallel.foreach

I am looking for almost similar solution. The scenario is same. I have parallel for each loop in c#.net. It calls 2 functions before actually hits the powershell code. The code snippet is below.

My question is, what is correct approach to call powershell script file in parallel using run space from c# code. Currently the issue is that powershell is in wait state indefinitely.

Please let me know improved or right way. I am not clear on the code you gave as example above, especially creating runspace pool and assigning to PS object. How or when do you call RemoteCommandInvoker(). I understand its a constructor, is that suffice. ?

My code snippet. The code is called from Prallel.ForEach. Here we pass IPdress and machine name. The script file is same.

```
public string ExecuteCommandDirect(string IpAddress, string machineName, string logFilePath, string powerShellPath, string PSLogFilePath) { String FullPsFilePath = powerShellPath; // path of powershell script file; String PsParameters = FullPsFilePath + " " + IpAddress + " " + machineName + " " + PSLogFilePath;
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    runspace.Open();

    //Console.WriteLine("Create pipeline & add commands....");
    // Create pipeline and add commands
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(PsParameters);

    // Execute Script
    Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
    AWSlogging.WriteLog("Invoking Script....", logFilePath);

    try
    {
        results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
    }

    // Close runspace
    runspace.Close();
    runspace.Dispose();

    //Console.WriteLine("Completed.Run Space closed...");
    AWSlogging.WriteLog("Completed.Run Space closed...", logFilePath);

    //Script results to string
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    //Console.WriteLine("Output....Start");
    AWSlogging.WriteLog("Output....Start", logFilePath);
```

Comment: In above comment I am also using earlier question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824139/powershell-c-sharp-host-multiple-concurrent-remote-command-invocations